# How to scp files to a VPS whose ip was blocked without the help of jump servers?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, scp, cloudflare, ip-blocking

The **IP** of my VPS was **blocked**. Sorry to mention but currently I might not have enough expense to apply to switch IP nor purchase new VPS as jump servers.

#### Status:

The VPS host itself is running normally, of course. But Its IP cannot be accessed in the region I'm living in.

[TCP and ICMP block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5u0Z.png)

#### What I achieved:

I made it to `ssh` it with the help of my former domain, the CloudFlare and some libs like `webssh`. The solution is simple: rediect the DNS of domain to cloudflare, so that all the HTTP/HTTPS flows will be passed by cloudflare. And use browser to visit my domain, then the local client on the VPS will access local service of its `sshd`.

[use SSH with the aid of CloudFlare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQjT.png)

#### Question:

Now, I can manage this VPS by the solution above, the web based SSH. But I've got a small blog site running on this VPS and I couldn't copy files from/to it. Here comes the question:

How could I achive `scp` in a similar pattern? Or are there ssh clients which can support such protocols like **HTTPS/WebSockets** which will enable me to transfer files? If there are some solutions other than `scp`, it could also be better. Thanks.

#### Q&A:

- Why use HTTP/HTTPS? No other protocols or ports?

  - Since currently I could only think up a solution based on CloudFlare to solve this problem. And 80/443 are the only ports cloudflare can work with in the network environment of certain country.
- What are you doing with VPS?

  - Personal technical blog.
  - Speed up the visit to code repositories like github. Without proxy on this VPS, the speed is only approx 10kb/s.

---

1st update: add more information.

Comment: Did your country block the VPS IP address, or did the VPS provider block your country? Either way the best solution is probably a VPN, but in the latter case the provider might also be compelled to cancel the service. You should backup everything as soon as possible.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you. I'll take care of the data. Your first assumption is right. I tested the IP via websites like ping.pe. Pings from most places of the world succeeded, and dramatically, all pings from nodes in certain country failed.